# How can I see all Wifi Passwords using netsh with 1 command?

Tags: powershell

I want to make an automated ducky script which will use the

```
netsh wlan show profile * key=clear > G:Profiles.txt
```

command or something similar to see all Wlan Credentials and write them to a file.

When I use the netsh wlan show profile * key=clear command I can just see the password of the top Wlan.

I am very sorry because all of it is going to be in German because I am German. But I have marked the spot where the Passwords are. I am really sorry. This is my first question on here.

Example:

```
Das Profil "?????? ???????" auf Schnittstelle WLAN:
=======================================================================

Angewendet: Profil für alle Benutzer

Profilinformationen
------------------- 
    Version                : 1
    Typ                    : Drahtlos-LAN
    Name                   : ?????? ???????
    Steuerungsoptionen     :
        Verbindungsmodus   : Automatisch verbinden
        Netzwerkübertragung  : Verbinden, nur wenn dieses Netzwerk überträgt
        Automatisch wechseln         : Nicht zu anderen Netzwerken wechseln.
        MAC-Randomisierung  : Deaktiviert

Konnektivitätseinstellungen
---------------------
    Anzahl von SSIDs        : 1
    SSID-Name              : "???"
    Netzwerktyp            : Infrastruktur
    Funktyp                : [ Beliebiger Funktyp ]
    Herstellererweiterung          : Nicht vorhanden

Sicherheitseinstellungen
------------------------ 
    Authentifizierung         : WPA2-Personal
    Verschlüsselung                 : CCMP
    Authentifizierung         : WPA2-Personal
    Verschlüsselung                 : GCMP
    Sicherheitsschlüssel   : Vorhanden
    Schlüsselinhalt            : Beispiel123  <--------------- This is the Password

Kosteneinstellungen 
------------------- 
    Kosten                 : Uneingeschränkt
    Überlastet              : Nein
    Datenlimit bald erreicht: Nein
    Über Datenlimit         : Nein
    Roaming                : Nein
    Kostenquelle            : Standard


Das Profil "WLANSoeNi" auf Schnittstelle WLAN:
=======================================================================

Angewendet: Profil für alle Benutzer

Profilinformationen
------------------- 
    Version                : 1
    Typ                    : Drahtlos-LAN
    Name                   : WLANSoeNi
    Steuerungsoptionen     :
        Verbindungsmodus   : Manuell verbinden
        Netzwerkübertragung  : Verbinden, nur wenn dieses Netzwerk überträgt
        Automatisch wechseln         : Nicht zu anderen Netzwerken wechseln.
        MAC-Randomisierung  : Deaktiviert

Konnektivitätseinstellungen
---------------------
    Anzahl von SSIDs        : 1
    SSID-Name              : "WLANSoeNi"
    Netzwerktyp            : Infrastruktur
    Funktyp                : [ Beliebiger Funktyp ]
    Herstellererweiterung          : Nicht vorhanden

Sicherheitseinstellungen
------------------------ 
    Authentifizierung         : WPA2-Personal
    Verschlüsselung                 : CCMP
    Authentifizierung         : WPA2-Personal
    Verschlüsselung                 : GCMP
    Sicherheitsschlüssel   : Vorhanden
                                                   <----------- This is where the other Password 
                                                                should be

Kosteneinstellungen 
------------------- 
    Kosten                 : Uneingeschränkt
    Überlastet              : Nein
    Datenlimit bald erreicht: Nein
    Über Datenlimit         : Nein
    Roaming                : Nein
    Kostenquelle            : Standard
```

---

Does anyone now a command that would really show all of them?

Comment: This question is a question on general software and would be better suited to be asked on SuperUser.

Comment: Agree with NineBerry, and this is not a PowerShell code issue. Yet, this sort of thing in samples all over the web. What did you search for?  It's your approach and not aksing for all you are after. This is not as simple as you are trying. As hackoo shows, it's a combination of commands, but it can be a one-pipelined command, in about 6-7 pipes. What is your use case for this? As when I see this, it's usually someone looking for help to scrape WALN networks that are not their own (ducky). aka a nefarious effort. Well, maybe a homework assignment for some hacking class you may be taking. ;-}.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do that is to be independent from any language !

So we should export all profiles in XML and parse them in order to extract what you want as data : You can give a try for this powershell script

---

```
cls
# We must execute this Powershell script with admin rights !
if (-Not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) 
{
  if ([int](Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BuildNumber) -ge 6000) 
  {

      $CommandLine = $MyInvocation.InvocationName
      Start -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $CommandLine
      Exit
   }
}

$outputFile = "$env:APPDATA\Wifi-Keys.txt"
if (Test-Path $outputFile) { Remove-Item $outputFile }
cmd /c mkdir wifi>nul 2>&1 | Out-Null;
cmd /c cd wifi | Out-Null;
netsh wlan export profile key=clear | Out-Null;
dir *.xml |% { $xml=[xml] (get-content $_) 
    $SSID = $xml.WLANProfile.SSIDConfig.SSID.name 
    $KeyPassword = $xml.WLANProfile.MSM.Security.sharedKey.keymaterial
    if ($SSID -ne $null) 
    {
        $SSID + ":" + $KeyPassword | Out-File -Append $outputFile -Encoding UTF8 -Force
    }    
}
Start $outputFile
```

---

EDIT : 21/09/2020 : Powershell script In one line :

---

```
netsh wlan show profiles | Select-String ":.*[a-zA-Z0-0-_]+" | % {"$_".split(":")[1].trim()} | % {netsh wlan show profile name=$_ key=clear}
```

Comment: Sure, but this can be done natively in PowerShell, using only the netsh cmd a proper string parsing. No external stuff, XML etc., needed.

Comment: @postanote Can you show me Without using XML How we can use netsh and extract a proprer string when the system is German ? Thank you !

Comment: Hackoo, I'm in the USA, and the last time I even looked at the German Language, was my highschool and early military days backn in the 1970's. ;-} So, I have no idea how it would play in German. Yet, it's just a matter of using netsh a couple of times and ForEach-Object 4 times, Select-String twice, and a PSCustomObject to output the name and password. I don't want ot just post it here as I don't want to aide and abed the OP in what seems a nafarious use, but I am told there is a way on SO, to connect in a 1 to 1 conversation, but I've never used that feature as I had no reas to date to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you absolutely need to use `netsh` to gather this.  But if you don't, the **WiFiProfileManagement** module is your friend in this case!  (this was all done in a PS 7.0.3 console, running in Admin mode)
Note, too, I didn't redirect to txt or other file. Simple enough though, but you'll have to grab the "Name" of each profile and pass that to this command, since the -ProfileName parameter doesn't take wildcards.

```
PS C:\Users\xxxxxxx\bin> Install-Module -Name WiFiProfileManagement
PS C:\Users\xxxxxxx\bin> Get-Command -Module WiFiProfileManagement

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Connect-WiFiProfile                                0.5.0.0    WiFiProfileManagement
Function        Get-WiFiAvailableNetwork                           0.5.0.0    WiFiProfileManagement
Function        Get-WiFiProfile                                    0.5.0.0    WiFiProfileManagement
Function        New-WiFiProfile                                    0.5.0.0    WiFiProfileManagement
Function        Remove-WiFiProfile                                 0.5.0.0    WiFiProfileManagement
Function        Set-WiFiProfile                                    0.5.0.0    WiFiProfileManagement


PS C:\Users\xxxxxxx\bin> Get-WiFiProfile

ProfileName               ConnectionMode Authentication Encryption Password
-----------               -------------- -------------- ---------- --------
foobar                    auto           WPA2PSK        AES
NETGEAR-5G-Guest          manual         open           none
Fi-foobar                 auto           WPA2PSK        AES
xxxxxxx                   auto           WPA2PSK        AES

PS C:\Users\xxxxxxx\bin> Get-WiFiProfile -ProfileName foobar -ClearKey

ProfileName               ConnectionMode Authentication Encryption Password
-----------               -------------- -------------- ---------- --------
Verizon-MiFi7730L-2C70    auto           WPA2PSK        AES        30d80266

PS C:\Users\xxxxxxx\bin>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running the command like this and see if it helps:

```
netsh wlan show profile * key=clear 2>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath "Path\to\out\file.txt"
```

Comment: Your code and William Higgs code do get all the profiles, it just does not get you all the passwords (your use case) for all profiles, which requires more string parsing. You are literally asking random folks on SO to help you write hacking code for your rubber ducky hak5 effort.  ;-}   I demo how to do this exact thing in risk management/security classes I teach and white hat pen-testing engagements I get assigned.